# Google maps zoom scrollbar does not appear on new version

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

I have a web-page [here](http://szkoz.com/hungarian-map/city/arad). It uses google maps and it worked well. Recently a new version of google maps was released where some changes were made. For instance, instead of `e.latLng.F`, `e.latLng.lng` and instead of `e.latLng.A`, `e.latLng.lat` should be used. So far, so good. However, for some reason, the zoom scrollbar cannot be seen. I know one can still zoom with mouse scrolling, however, what about devices where mouse scroll is not defined, like a laptop with a touchpad?

This is a part of initialization:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: lat, lng: lon},
    zoom: 14
};

if (!administrator) {
    mapOptions.mapTypeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I believe I should define an attribute for `mapOptions`, but I do not know what should be defined there. When I searched for this on google, I have not found the answer. It is possible that I will find out the answer soon, but anyway, I ask the question here to make sure that others will have an answer to this question in the future. Thanks.

EDIT:

At [this](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_controls_modify1) page I can see a zoom control. This is the code there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:7,
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

if I modify it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: { lat: 51.508742, lng: -0.120850},
    zoom:7,
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the zoom control is still displayed. I wonder why is the zoom control displayed at w3c and not at my end, since:

- both the example and my code uses a `div`
- the properties are initialized in a similar manner
- the map is initialized in a similar manner
- the dom listener is initialized in a similar manner

Comment: Here I have see no helpful information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom control was always displayed, but the footer overflown it. It seems that the zoom control is positioned to the right bottom by default, while earlier it was positioned to the left top by default. The solution is either to make sure that the `div` where the map is displayed is displayed fully, or to initialize the position of the zoom control, like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: lat, lng: lon},
    zoom: 14,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

They've removed the scroll bar from the newest API, but they left the `+` and `-` zoom controls. Strangely, I see that your map doesn't have those either.

[This article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v322-controls-diff) about the changes made to the map controls might be useful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have realized what the problem was: the zoom control was moved from left top to right bottom and it was not visible because of the footer. It is important to note that the zoom control's type and default position was modified, see my answer.